# Extending your object with function and refer to the current object

Tags: javascript

Given my object :

```
obj = {}
obj['prop1'] = 1
obj['prop2'] = 2
```

If I extend it using underscore with a function property like this :

```
objHelper = {
              normalizeValue: function(somerules, myObj){
                /* .. some logic involving myObj and somerules*/
              }
        }

_.extend(obj, objHelper)
```

So when I'm invoking the function on the `obj` I do it like this :

```
obj.normalizeValue('somerule', obj);
```

So I'm passing self to the object method which seems kind of odd. Is there a way to access the object on which this method is being invoked on i.e. from the example above :

```
normalizeValue: function(somerules){
                    /* .. some logic involving myObj and somerules*/

                          var myObj = someMagicMethod();
                  }
```

Comment: Just use `this`. [Learn more about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). It works because the value of `this` is determined at run/call time, not at definition time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to access the object on which this method is being invoked on

Yes, the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) does exactly do that.

```
objHelper = {
    normalizeValue: function(somerules){
        /* .. some logic involving somerules and the target of the method call */
        var myObj = this;
    }
};
```